# How to re-use components that change state with React & Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, reusability, code-reuse

I am coming across a reusability conundrum in my React/Redux app. I have coded reusable React components, such as dropdowns and sliders, and I am storing the state values in my Redux Store. It is dawning on me now that anytime any JSX instance of the component changes state, all other instances of that component also change state. They all begin to mimic each other, whereas I need them to operate independently. I also want to initialize state differently in the different instances of the component, and can't figure out a way to do this. For example, for a slider, I want the beginning and ending value of the slider range to be different in different instances of the component. This would be easy to do through React's normal props system, but I am getting confused on how to do it via Redux.

I've researched this a bit and it seems the solution is to add unique IDs to each instance of the component in the Redux store. But I need specifics on where to add the ID (the reducer? the action creator? the component?) and how to have everything flow so that the right component is getting their state changed.

This is my reducer:

```
    const INITIAL_STATE = {
      slots: 100, 
      step: 5,
      start: 35,
      end: 55,
    };

const sliderReducer = (state=INITIAL_STATE, action ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "MIN_SELECTED":
        console.log("Min Selected");
        return {
          ...state,
          start: action.payload
        };
      case "MAX_SELECTED":
        console.log("Max Selected");
        return {
          ...state,
          end: action.payload
        };
      default:
          return state;
    }
}

export default sliderReducer;
```

this is my action creator:

```
//Slider Minimum Value Selection Action Creator
export const selectMinValue = (value) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "MIN_SELECTED",
      payload: value
    });
  };
};

//Slider Maximum Value Selection Action Creator
export const selectMaxValue = (value) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "MAX_SELECTED",
      payload: value
    });
  };
};
```

the component code is too long to paste, but it's event handlers for onDrag events and JSX for the slider essentially.

Comment: Why don't you use internal state? Are your components functional or class based? Either way I would avoid REDUX altogether for maintaining state....

Comment: My app is in Redux so I'm trying to keep a single state store, which is best practice. Surely there must be a way to write reusable components with Redux. Otherwise why would anyone use it. My components are both class and functions, depending.

Answer (score 0):

You could give each instance a unique id. This would allow you to pass the id to the redux store where you could hold an object or array that would store each instance's data based off on the unique key. You could hold another redux variable that handles unique id generation.

For example you could have a state value for each reusable component called "id" initialized to "null". In the redux store, you could have another "id_counter" that keeps track of the next usable id to assign to a reusable component. During component initialization, you can make a call to redux to retrieve the most recent "id_counter" and then increment "id_counter" by 1. If you start "id_counter" at 0, you can have id's that can access a zero-based array. So, then you can have another item in the redux store, "data", that is an array that grows with each new id that is added. This "data" variable can hold data for each of your reusable components.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion - any chance you can write some quick pseudo code here so I know what you mean exactly? Am I giving each JSX instance a unique ID via React props? i.e. <Slider id="1"/>? Then how do I make the state change conditional on that ID? I'm not sure where to put that code and how to stop the state from changing if I am not on the right ID component.